# How to limit the number of files MultipleFileField WTForms Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

The main requirement I need is to limit the amount of files that the end user can upload to the system.

I would also like the files to be listed so that the end user can see what files he uploaded and delete them.

```
class NameForm(FlaskForm):   
    field       = MultipleFileField('fieldname',validators= [])
```

I understand that you can make functions and incorporate them into the validator, I am currently doing the verification with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a [`MultipleFileField`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.MultipleFileField) but limit the number of files that can be uploaded at once, you can use a [`Length`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/validators/#wtforms.validators.Length) type validator.
In combination with [`InputRequired`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/validators/#wtforms.validators.InputRequired) you can also require at least one file.

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import MultipleFileField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length
from werkzeug.datastructures import CombinedMultiDict

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret here'

class UploadForm(FlaskForm):
    files = MultipleFileField('Files', 
        validators=[
            InputRequired(message='At least one file is required.'), 
            Length(max=3, message='A maximum of 3 files are allowed.'), 
        ]
    )

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    form = UploadForm(CombinedMultiDict((request.files, request.form)))
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Handle the uploaded files here!
        print(form.files.data)
    return render_template('upload.html', **locals())
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <div>
            {{ form.files.label() }}
            {{ form.files() }}
            {% if form.files.errors -%}
            <ul>
                {% for error in form.files.errors -%}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor -%}
            </ul>
            {% endif -%}
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

In order to display a list of uploaded files and delete individual files, we need more information about your application. This also applies if you want to limit the maximum number of files a user can upload in total.